# coloring a graph with minimum colors

Tags: algorithm, graph

I want to color a graph such that **for any vertex v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub>**, if there are n paths between them:

p<sub>1</sub> = (v<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>11</sub>,p<sub>12</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>) 
p<sub>2</sub> = (v<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>21</sub>,p<sub>22</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>) 
...
p<sub>n</sub> = (v<sub>1</sub>, p<sub>n1</sub>,p<sub>n2</sub>,v<sub>2</sub>)

(p<sub>11</sub>,p<sub>12</sub> are vertices of the path, the path has four vertices)

p<sub>i</sub> means a path, p<sub>i1</sub> and p<sub>i2</sub> are the two vertices between v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub>.

There mustn't exist two paths p<sub>i</sub> and p<sub>j</sub> such that c(p<sub>i1</sub>) = c(p<sub>j1</sub>) and c(p<sub>i2</sub>) = c(p<sub>j2</sub>), where c(v) means the color of vertex v.

Simply speaking, the paths between v<sub>1</sub> and v<sub>2</sub> should be distinguishable.

Our goal is to minimize the number of colors.

Is there a coloring algorithm satisfying above conditions?  Star coloring definitely satisfies the conditions but it needs more colors.

Comment: Are we talking about _simple_ paths only? If we can revisit vertices, then the problem is quite easily reducible to the usual coloring problem.

Comment: I don't understand this syntax, `p1 = (v1, p11,p12,v2)`. p1 being a path connecting to vertices v1 and v2, but what is this two other arguments in the middle, what do they even mean for you?

Comment: @ShaneHsu I read that as `p1 = (v1, v11, v12, ..., v2)`. If that's the correct interpretation, it's an interesting problem. If not, it's a different (interesting?) problem

Comment: @JanDvorak Maybe, because it also mention `c(pi2)` is the color of a vertex, which will indicate `p11` is a vertex. This is quite confusing. Anyway, it's best for the asker to come out and answer our questions.

Comment: @ShaneHsu I consider your question resolved (noting that `c(pi2)` is a vertex color). I'm still wondering about mine. If any [walk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Path_(graph_theory)) is available, it greatly simplifies the problem, and I can write an answer. If not, I can only give an upper bound.

Comment: Only simple paths. p11 and p12 are vertexes, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @JanDvorak, any walk is possible.

Comment: @XinliNiu umm.... simple path = vertices may not be repeated within a single path; walk = vertices and edges may be repeated within a single walk. Both can't be true.

Comment: @JanDvorak,Sorry I am not familiar with graph theory. I mean only simple paths. There are only two vertexes between v1 and v2. This is a problem I met when dealing with a network problem.

Comment: This is getting interesting, now that we know the paths have a bounded length

Comment: @JanDvorak See this picture http://www.cnblogs.com/nxlhero/gallery/image/127205.html  My goal is to color the routers to make the paths distinguishable.

Comment: Do you have the problem description in Chinese, paste it to pastebin and I can maybe better describe it for you.

Comment: I don't have a rigorous proof but I think this should work. Suppose you search through the graph and find a pair of vertices vi and vj that have the maximum number of paths N between them. Then the maximum number of colors must be bounded by N since we have vi and vj at the ends (so there's no way to get confused between these paths and others). Let the vertices at distance 1 from vi be colored in such a way. Vertices at distance 2 from vi can be colored by a permutation of the above set of colors and so on.

Comment: Let me clarify, so for your example in the image, the answer is 2 right? We can color everything as black except R3 and the right red vertex.

Comment: What are you coloring, edges or vertex? Is there any condition on coloring?ie. adjacent vertices/edges cannot be same color?

Comment: One clarification c(pi1) = c(pj1) and c(pi2) = c(pj2) must hold true can mean individually both or together (either one of them) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is my answer given how I understood your question. You are trying to find out the minimum number of colours you can use to connect **N** 2-vertex paths.

Try solving the opposite : given **x** colours how many unique paths can you generate. It was not clear from question whether first and second vertex can be of same color so I will take the two possibilities:

1. Same colour allowed (permutation with replacement)

   Given **x** colours max **x<sup>2</sup>** permutations can be generated. So **N** paths will need at least **√N** colours.

   For colours = RGB
   vertices = RR,RG,RB,GR,GG,GB,BR,BG,BB
2. Same colour not allowed (permutation without replacement)

   Given **x** colours max **<sup>x</sup>P<sub>2</sub>** permutations can be generated. That is
   x<sup>2</sup>-x ≥ N. Solving the quadratic inequality will give you

   **x** ≥ (1 ± √(1 + 4 **N**))/2

   **x** = floor((1 + √(1 + 4 **N**))/2)

   For colours = RGB
   vertices = RG,RB,GR,GB,BR,BG
   (Given 7 paths you need 4 colours)